# Make a "Key Released" In Python With No Library?

Tags: python, keyboard, logic, pyglet, keyrelease

I have been trying to use some "key released" functions from libraries like [pynput](https://pypi.org/project/pynput/) and so, but I ran in to the problem that if I try using them together with a library called [pyglet](http://pyglet.org/), that is a library for window-based apps, it won't let me and the program would crash.

I was wondering if there is any way detect key releases without libraries.

P.S: I've tried using the `on_key_release` function from pyglet but it was buggy for me and even though I wrote something for it to upon key release it usually didn't do it. I have checked my code a thousand times and it's not a problem on my part.

```
Pressing = False # var to indicate when the user is doing a long press and when he is not
@window.event
def on_key_release(symbol, modifiers):
    global Pressing
    if((symbol == key.A) | (symbol == key.S) | (symbol == key.W) | (symbol == key.D)):
        Pressing = False
    pass
```

and that code causes my player to freeze after i start moving him, and it does this even if i do nothing and just leach the whole on_key_release dunction empty. really weird.

Comment: This sounds like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You should probably ask why it was buggy with Pyglet instead of trying to patch in more problems to solve your original problem. `on_key_release` has never been buggy for me (see my other answer on your [other problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58500680/929999) for an example code)

Comment: ok thanks :) will try that

Comment: Could you perhaps paste your `on_key_release` code as well? And if possible, paste a minimal executable example that we can run/try with?

Comment: Ah, so the problem is that the character freezes? I see why if so, `on_key_release` is when you're releasing **any key**, and since you're no longer holding down `A` for instance, `S`, `W` and `D` will be `False` too. I could give you a quick example of how you should do it instead if you want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, your issue is most likely that you're doing `Pressing = False` if **any** key is released. Forcing your player object to freeze due to `Pressing` being `False` as soon as you release any of your keys.

To work around this, you should store the states of your keys in a variable (I'll call it `self.keys`), and just before you render stuff, update/check the keys and update your player object accordingly.

Here's a working example of movement on a player object (a red square in this case):

```
from pyglet import *
from pyglet.gl import *

key = pyglet.window.key

class main(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__ (self, width=800, height=600, fps=False, *args, **kwargs):
        super(main, self).__init__(width, height, *args, **kwargs)
        self.x, self.y = 0, 0

        self.keys = {}

        self.mouse_x = 0
        self.mouse_y = 0

        square = pyglet.image.SolidColorImagePattern((255, 0, 0, 255)).create_image(40, 40)
        self.player_object = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(square, x=self.width/2, y=self.height/2)

        self.alive = 1

    def on_draw(self):
        self.render()

    def on_close(self):
        self.alive = 0

    def on_mouse_motion(self, x, y, dx, dy):
        self.mouse_x = x

    def on_key_release(self, symbol, modifiers):
        try:
            del self.keys[symbol]
        except:
            pass

    def on_key_press(self, symbol, modifiers):
        if symbol == key.ESCAPE: # [ESC]
            self.alive = 0

        self.keys[symbol] = True

    def render(self):
        self.clear()

        ## Movement logic,
        #  check if key.W is in self.keys (updated via key_press and key_release)
        if key.W in self.keys:
            self.player_object.y += 1
        if key.S in self.keys:
            self.player_object.y -= 1
        if key.A in self.keys:
            self.player_object.x -= 1
        if key.D in self.keys:
            self.player_object.x += 1

        self.player_object.draw()

        self.flip()

    def run(self):
        while self.alive == 1:
            self.render()

            # -----------> This is key <----------
            # This is what replaces pyglet.app.run()
            # but is required for the GUI to not freeze
            #
            event = self.dispatch_events()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = main()
    x.run()
```

I've moved away from `@window.event` because it's easier for me to just copy paste this class/inheritance example since I had it laying around. But you could apply this logic any way you want. Just make sure you don't defined a solid state of pressing or not pressing, check individual keys and update accordingly before you render.